# How to prevent overlapping of arrows?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, data-visualization

I'm trying to plot multiple arrows to and from different points. I'm using `pyplot.quiver` and here's my result. 
[image]

As can be seen, in many places the arrows between two points are overlapping each other. However, I want something similar to this image below where the arrows instead of overlapping are juxtaposed against each other.

[image]

I realise that any two points can be connected by only one straight line so my method of simply passing in the list of `x and y lists` is probably wrong. I am looking for the best possible method to ensure that the arrows are **next to each other instead of on top of each other**

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT (16/06/19)**: I stumbled upon a Python library called [Networkx](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/index.html) which allows to analyse, visualise, and do other stuff related to network data and that's what I used to create [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jawQJ.png). It has nice functions for drawing two juxtaposed arrows between a pair of points and trying other things - curved arrows, changing the arrowhead etc.

Comment: There is no inbuilt option for this. But of course you can calculate the coordinates of the arrows such that they don't overlap.

Comment: I already have the starting and ending coordinates for every arrow. How do I progress from there on? I'm thinking finding the pairs of arrows between any two points and then adding and subtracting a small scalar (say, 2) from the x,y coordinates of both of the arrows respectively?

Comment: Yep, in the simple case! Of course one can make it arbitrarily complicated by finding the offset needed in pixel coordinates perpendicular to the arrow direction instead.

Comment: In that case, I'll have to find the pairs of column values (which warrants a new question). Thank you anyway!